# Recurrence functions with if statements

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am having some trouble building this recurrence relation.

We have three strings:

```
x=x1x2x3....xn

y=y1y2y3....ym

z=z1z2z3....zm
```

The problem is to find the length of the longest sequence that is a subsequence of all three sequences.

The recurrence I have built looks like this:

```
T(i,j,k)= O(1)                       if i=0 or j=0 or k=0
          T(i-1,j-1,k-1)             if(x[i]==y[j]==z[k])
          max(T(i-1,j,k)+T(i,j-1,k)
               +T(i,j,k-1))          otherwise
 where i is the length of x
       j is the length of y
       k is the length of z
```

I was wondering if this was correct, since i am not sure if we can use if(x[i]==y[j]==z[k]) as a case

Comment: Such a condition is most certainly *allowed* (why do you think it wouldn't be?), although to check whether your overall recurrence is correct you should run through an example and check that it returns the correct result. Although big-O doesn't belong there, on the assumption that you're trying to get the length, and not how long it will take to get the length.